# Pullback square with two identical sides

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, pullback

I'm wondering if any known property holds for a pullback square of the following form:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y @>{g}>> X \\
@V{h}VV @V{f}VV \\
Y @>{g}>> X
\end{CD}
$$
In particular, when working in a topos with $g$ mono and $f$ and $h$ idempotent arrows, can we deduce something more? I was really hoping that $h$ would be an isomorphism, but I can't find neither a proof nor a counterexample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple source of counterexamples.

Let $Y = X$ and $g = 1_X$. Then you have a pullback square if and only if $h=f$. (and also, the square commutes if and only if $h=f$)